# How to make a file detected by anti virus

Tags: antivirus, .net, c++

I know this question is kind of stupid but I am testing a virus database and I would like to know any kind of code in c++ or C#/VB.net that would be detected as virus by an antivirus, without actually having do download an antivirus.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for the "[EICAR Standard Anti-Virus Test File](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html)"?

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard file treated by all AV software I have used - [the EICAR test file](http://www.eicar.org/86-0-Intended-use.html) but this is used for testing the deployment and integration of a malware scanner, not its database. The only practical way to test the latter is with a *very* large number of live viruses.